# CSS not working in Internet Explorer 10 and above

Tags: html, css

Here is my code for `IE9` and above:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
    #bottom p{
        font-size:10pt!important;
    }

    #pop_cities{
        font-size:14pt !important;
        font-weight:bold !important;
        padding-right:10px !important;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

How can I apply these style for the version 9 of Internet Explorer and above?

Comment: `IE10` and `11` don't support conditional `CSS`. It's probably a better option to fix the underlying problem.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe you shouldn't be detecting the browser / version but the features it supports.

Answer (score 5):

Conditional comments are no longer supported:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

They don't work for version 10 and greater.

There is a hack for Internet Explorer 10, which you might want to use:

```
. ie10 #hack{
  /* Only works in IE10 */
}
```

Maybe you have to arm yourself with some JavaScript for the fight against the future versions of Internet Explorer, if you can't fix the underlying problem. For example with `JQuery`:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
  $("html").addClass("ie10");
}
```

As @Spudley mentioned, the [`$_browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/) property is **deprecated and already removed** in the newer version of jQuery. Maybe it's better to check the browser for e certains feature you need. For example with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). This is also recommended in the JQuery documentation.

Comment: Please note that jQuery's `$.browser` is also no longer supported, and has been removed from recent jQuery versions. Also, I would strongly recommend avoiding CSS hacks. There are other options if you really need something browser specific, but most of the time the real answer is that you don't actually need browser specific code for modern browsers; IE10 and IE11 are pretty good at being standards compliant.

Comment: @Spudley I've added your information to my answer. I hope you don't mind. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional comments supported IE9 and below version
IE 10+ browser support @media screen

```
 @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
 /*css*/
}
```